# Firebase Firestore comment tree architecture

Tags: firebase, tree, schema, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a Reddit/HackerNews style tree of comments as part of a project, and am trying out Firestore as a database solution. However, I'm unsure as to the correct design reading through the docs. In a SQL database I would use numeric keys like:

```
0
1.0
1.1
1.1.1
0.0
```

to represent my tree. However, numeric keys like that seem to be a Firebase antipattern. The other route is using an actual tree in the json where a post is represented like:

```
{
  uid: 'A0000',
  content: 'foo',
  children: [
    {uid:..., content:..., children: []}]
}
```

but supposedly deep trees are bad in Firestore. As I understand it the reason deep trees are bad is that you have to fetch the whole thing, but in my case I'm not sure if that's a problem. A client fetching a post would fetch the root content node and the first 20 or so child trees. That *could* be a pretty big fetch, but not insanely so.

Does anyone know of a good standard way to implement this kind of structure?

Extra: Here is the more verbose expression of what the structure should look like once the client processes it.

```js
{
  uid: 0,
  title: 'Check out this cat!',
  body: 'It\'s pretty cute! This **text** is [markdown](link), so it can have ' +
    'links and *stuff*. Yay!',
  poster: {
    uid: 0,
    name: 'VivaLaPanda',
    aviUrl: 'badlink',
  },
  posted: '2018-03-28',
  children: [{
      uid: 0,
      body: 'This is a comment, it\'s angry!',
      poster: {
        uid: 0,
        name: 'VivaLaPanda',
        aviUrl: 'badlink',
      },
      posted: '2018-03-20',
      children: [{
        uid: 0,
        body: 'This is a comment, it\'s neutral!',
        poster: {
          uid: 0,
          name: 'Steve',
          aviUrl: 'badlink',
        },
        posted: '2018-03-20',
        children: [{
          uid: 0,
          body: 'This is a comment, it\'s neutral!',
          poster: {
            uid: 0,
            name: 'Craig',
            aviUrl: 'badlink',
          },
          posted: '2018-04-10',
          children: []
        }, ]
      }, ]
    },
    {
      uid: 0,
      body: 'This is a comment, it\'s happy!',
      poster: {
        uid: 0,
        name: 'Craig',
        aviUrl: 'badlink',
      },
      posted: '2018-03-28',
      children: []
    },
  ]
};
```

Edit:

While I've marked this as answered because there *is* an answer, I'm still really interested in seeing something more elegant/efficient.

Edit2:

For posterity: I ended up deciding that any Firebase solution was hopelessly convoluted and just used DGraph for the data, with Firebase sitting in front for Auth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is tough since the structure you have is naturally recursive. The obvious options are each comment is a new document in a collection and each reply is a single document in the same collection.

Each comment as a new document could work something like this. Each comment has a "postId" attribute which dictates which post it belongs to. Some comments, those which are replies to other comments, have a "replyToId". These two attribute in conjunction allow your client app to:

1. Get the top level comments (look for comments with the correct postId and which don't have replyToId). Top level comments allows you to limit the size of payloads if you need to worry about that in the future.
2. Get all comments (look for comments with the correct postId only). If you don't care about payload sizes you can get everything and figure out the tree structure on the client.
3. Get replies to a particular comment if you want "see replies" YouTube style comments interaction (looks for comments which have a particular replyToId). This works well in conjunction with 1. for limiting payload sizes.

But the logic here is obviously complex.

Comment: So in this model the client would fetch the root, and then first children,and then second children, etc.?

Comment: Yes or fetch all comments. I think your Reddit style comments might be best implemented with the additional of a web API that uses MemCache or similar. You then just fetch all comments on the web API and cache them with MemCache and only serve up part of the results set to the client to save bandwidth.

Comment: Okay, I have some ideas on how to make your design work for me. I'm gonna leave this open until my bounty expires to see if I can get another perspective, but otherwise I'll consider this the answer

Comment: @AdrianSmith I would be interested to see what you end up with; please share it here if you can

Comment: Is there any advantage here of using a parent ref versus subcollections. From what I can see in the docs they are functionally equivelant

Comment: @AdrianSmith in what way would you use subcollections here? The one thing to take into account is that Firestore queries are shallow so documents in a subcollection won't be returned when you fetch the parent document.

Comment: Yeah, but I can fetch the subcollection after I've fetched the parent collection, exactly like what I would do if I had a "parent" ref.

Comment: @AdrianSmith I think parent ref might actually be the better solution here, simply because you won't have to worry about orphaned subcollections (deleting a parent document doesn't need the subcollection when you use the Firestore APIs/client).

Comment: I would still need to worry about orphans, because I could delete a parent that has child comments pointing towards it.

Comment: @AdrianSmith I guess the logic for deleting a comment and all its replies would be to keep recursively looking for comments which reference the one you want to delete until there are none and work your way backward

Comment: Which is the same case for subcollections

Comment: @AdrianSmith except, subcollections without their parent doc are essentially hidden (unless you explicitly know their path). At least with the parentRef and everything under a single "comments" collection approach, you can find the orphans retroactively. But generally avoiding them is best

Answer (score 8):

Your children approach could be really messy if there are a lot of people commenting on eachother. A nicer approach would be the following structure for every comment:

```
// single comment

postUid // <- random generated by firebase
{
    postedBy: userUid
    postedTime: timestamp
    postIsChildOfUid: postUid // <- reference to an other post (optional if the comment didn't respond to another comment(top-level comment))
}
```

This doesn't even require nesting at all :). You can generate easily now a comment tree with this approach, but this has to be client side. But that should be easy!